# Scaling a figure to show long annotations

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have annotated a color bar to a categorical heatmap with lengthy names. When plotting, those names are not fully visible. `plt.tight_layout()` breaks the arrangement of elements, sometimes not showing heatmap ticks or scaling the color bar and heatmap out of proportions. How could I automatically make the figure bigger without introducing these other issues?

Here's a sample:

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib

n_labs = 4
labels = np.floor(np.random.rand(10, 10) * n_labs)
names = np.array(['a'*20] * n_labs)

bounds = np.linspace(-0.5, n_labs - 0.5, n_labs + 1)
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, n_labs)
fmt = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(
    lambda z, pos: names[norm(z)]
)

plt.figure()
plt.suptitle('Title')
sns.heatmap(
    labels, cmap=plt.get_cmap('copper', n_labs), square=True, linewidths=1, vmax=n_labs,
    cbar_kws=dict(
        ticks=np.arange(n_labs), format=fmt,
        boundaries=bounds, drawedges=True
    ),
)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Results without and with `tight_layout`:

[image: Without]

[image: With]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that seaborn is doing some weird calculations of boundary boxes; regardless of this, I also have had many issues with the "clever guesses" of `plt.tight_layout()` before, I now generally use `gridspec` to have more granular control over the figure layout (with added benefits of control over multiple subplots):

```
from matplotlib import gridspec

####
omitting your data code here  for simplicity...
####

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(3,3),dpi=96,) ##### figure size in inch
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1, ##### a 1x1 subplot grid
    left=0.1,right=0.7,     #####<—— play with these values, 
    bottom=0.0,top=1.0,     #####    they give the margins as percentage of the figure
    wspace=0.0,hspace=0.0,  #####<—- this controls additional padding around the subplot
)
ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0]) ##### add the gridspec subplot gs[0]

ax.set_title('Title')
sns.heatmap(
    labels, cmap=plt.get_cmap('copper', n_labs), square=True, linewidths=1, vmax=n_labs,
    cbar_kws=dict(
        ticks=np.arange(n_labs), format=fmt,
        boundaries=bounds, drawedges=True,
        shrink=0.6
    ),

    ax=ax #####<—— it is important to let seaborn know which subplot to use
)
```

————————

In order to have things *more or less automatic*, try plotting like this:

```
fig,axes=plt.subplots(1,2, gridspec_kw = {'width_ratios':[20, 1]},figsize=(3,3))
cbar_ax=axes[1]
ax=axes[0]

ax.set_title('Title')
sns.heatmap(
    labels, cmap=plt.get_cmap('copper', n_labs), square=True, linewidths=1, vmax=n_labs,
    cbar_kws=dict(
        ticks=np.arange(n_labs), format=fmt,
        boundaries=bounds, drawedges=True,
        shrink=0.1,
    ),
    cbar_ax=cbar_ax, #####< it is important to let seaborn know which subplot to use
    ax=ax #####< it is important to let seaborn know which subplot to use
)


plt.tight_layout()    
plt.show()
```

Here you're creating two subplots (`ax` and `cbar_ax`) with a `width_ratio` of `20:1` and then tell the `sns.heatmap` to actually use these axes. `plt.tight_layout()` appears to be working better, and as automatic as possible, but will still run into issues (e.g. by setting `figsize=(2,2)` it will throw `ValueError: left cannot be >= right`

Comment: Thank you for the method. It works, but it's hardly an automatic way of scaling the axes. The problem persists with even longer annotations and correspondingly with shorter ones there is extra space.

Comment: @Felix I've updated my answer with another potential solution; while it is more "automatic", it may still produce errors in certain edge cases. Full manual control will always be better than the automatic guesses of `tight_layout()`!

Comment: Fair enough, it seems that this only expanding the figure right based on the string length is either impossible or very difficult to achieve. And this more automatic solution basically achieves what the `tight_layout` already did but worse (the cbar overlaps with the heatmap), so I'll stick to the original. My reason to wanting this automatic solution is that I intend to produce many such figures, and there's no way to know how long the annotations are. Thanks regardless!

Comment: @Felix couldn't you try to force a line break into the annotations? (Or do they een need to be that long?) I'm thinking something along the lines of `for t in cbar_ax.get_yticklabels(): ### evaluate len(t) and modify accordingly`